# Mysql return one single row from result NOT EXISTS (multi row return)

Tags: mysql, row, not-exists

I really can't deal with this piece of code ...
I need help ... I searched on the forum but no topic about return 1 row < multi row

Here it is in a for loop:

```
for (global.id_increment = 0; global.id_increment < global.max_increment; global.id_increment++)
{
     q = GMSQL_QueryExecute(db,
            "INSERT INTO Users (id, name, password, age)
             SELECT " + string(global.id_increment) + ",'User', 'Pass', 14
             FROM dual
             WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT id
                FROM Users
                WHERE Users.id = " + string(global.id_increment) + "
                LIMIT 1
            )
     ");      
}
```

- GMSQL_QueryExecute is a DLL for GMS
- This script is affected to a sprite (object) for adding row in empty id.row

more explained

```
ID Users :  01   02   03   04   05   06   07   08   09   (all rows)
            01   02        04   05   06             09   (case empty)
                     03                  07   08         (query actual return)
                     03                                  (the return searched :
                                                       the "first match" enable)
```

I don't know why LIMIT 1 doesn't work

So I really need help

---

How to deal with it?

Comment: Either records exist, or they don't: placing a `LIMIT` on the subquery will not affect `EXISTS()`.  Are you simply looking to [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-auto-increment.html) the `id`?

Comment: Are you just trying to prevent users from being created with duplicate values for `id`?  Can you alter the table structure to create a `UNIQUE KEY` on the `id` column?

Comment: Are you sure this is MySQL? I don't think it has the special `dual` table.

Comment: @Barmar: "[You are permitted to specify `DUAL` as a dummy table name in situations where no tables are referenced](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html)".

Comment: Lotharyx, i thought than to put the process and after manage unique key ... but manage the unique key by first ... i resolve the problem up there ... so thanks, my problem is resolved